# WPF Animation of Window.Top stops at different values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i build a "windows 8 startmenu"-like application. I use an animation that slide the menu window from bottom into the screen. The animation uses Window.Top to animate.

But everytime i run the Application, the Value of "Top" in

```
wAnimation.Completed += (s1, e1) =>
                {
                    SizeChanged += (s2, e2) => { if (e2.HeightChanged) Top = businessLogic.CalculateWindowTopLeft(Width, Height).Y; };
                };
```

jitters between ~5 to ~15 points, when (read carefully !) i have set the breakpoint on the "SizeChanged"-Line. That means BEFORE "businessLogic.CalculateWindowTopLeft" is executed. And that means, the "Top" i see is the end value for Top of the animation.

Why the hell is he doing that ??? Is that a strange W32/WPF/wHandle Bug-thing ? I do not understand this behaviour.

Extra-Comment:

First i had the animation code in xaml and bind it (like you normally do). To debug i have done this in code-behind (see below). Also i tried (see below) to set the bindings after the animation occurred, so that the bindings could not do something wrong. The behaviour was in all cases exact the same (wrong).

Tell me, if you still need the xaml code, so i post it then.

(Sorry for the bad english, i´m a german guy).

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        InitializeComponent();

        businessLogic = new BusinessLogic(new DataModel(), new DataPersister());

        var vm = new MainWindowViewModel(businessLogic, new DialogService());

        DataContext = vm;

        businessLogic.Load();

        Width = businessLogic.DataModel.MenuWidth;
        Height = businessLogic.DataModel.MenuHeight;
        Opacity = 0;

        windowPosition = businessLogic.CalculateWindowTopLeft(Width, Height);

        Top = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - (Height * 0.50);
        //Top = windowPosition.Y;
        Left = windowPosition.X;

        Background = businessLogic.GetTaskBarPreviewSolidColorBrush(1);

        vm.CloseRequested += (s) => Hide();
        Deactivated += (s, e) => { if (!vm.SettingsOpened) Close(); };

        Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            var wAnimation = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation(windowPosition.Y, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300)));
            wAnimation.FillBehavior = System.Windows.Media.Animation.FillBehavior.Stop;
            wAnimation.AccelerationRatio = 0.1;
            wAnimation.From = Top;

            wAnimation.Completed += (s1, e1) =>
                {
                    SizeChanged += (s2, e2) => { if (e2.HeightChanged) Top = businessLogic.CalculateWindowTopLeft(Width, Height).Y; };
                };

            var oAnimation = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation(businessLogic.DataModel.MenuOpacity, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 600)));
            oAnimation.FillBehavior = System.Windows.Media.Animation.FillBehavior.Stop;
            oAnimation.AccelerationRatio = 0.1;
            oAnimation.From = 0;

            oAnimation.Completed += (s3, e3) =>
            {
                Binding myBinding = new Binding();
                myBinding.Source = DataContext;
                myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("DataModel.MenuOpacity");
                myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, Window.OpacityProperty, myBinding);
            };

            BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, wAnimation);
            BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, oAnimation);
        };

        Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I detect that    wAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd    works. But i need to change the Top Value, so i can not use "HoldEnd" and the question also stays the same: Why behaves it like that, when i use FillBehaviour "Stop" ?

Answer (score 0):

Interessting...

this very (!) simple code creates the exact same behaviour. Start it 10 times and you see what i mean. I can not believe that... :)

```
namespace SlideTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Deactivated += (s, e) => Close();
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="SlideTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="200" Top="500" Left="700"
    WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Aqua">
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Duration="00:00:.30">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:.30" AccelerationRatio="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Top" From="1400" To="455" FillBehavior="Stop"></DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: Of course you must set your height etc. to your appropriate screen dimensions. In the case above i use a 1440x900 screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Not really nice, but the only one that works. I never will understand that "FillBehaviour=Stop" behaviour. To me it seems like a bug (even if i can´t believe that) or some strange in-deep "nature of wpf animation"-thing...

So, here we go:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Deactivated += (s, e) => Close();

        myAnimation.Completed += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, null);

                myStoryboard.Remove();
            };
    }
}

<Window x:Class="SlideTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="200" Top="455" Left="700"
    WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Aqua">
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Duration="00:00:.30" Name="myStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:.30" AccelerationRatio="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Top" From="1400" To="455" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Name="myAnimation"></DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Hope this saves someone else a lot of time...